# how do simple mobile game servers are built?

Tags: mobile, unity-game-engine

I'm really new to programming, and I wonder how simple mobile game servers (like flappy bird) are built to store the scores that user made.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to programming maybe instead of programming your own backend engine is better to use some APIs developed by third party developers. Some examples are on [Parse](https://parse.com/products/unity), [App42](http://api.shephertz.com/app42-docs/leaderboard-service/?sdk=unity) or [Gamedonia](http://www.gamedonia.com/unity3d). This APIs allows to save data easily and to not have to build your own servers.

Answer (score 0):

The three things you need to know how to do:

- Write a program that talks to another program over the internet
- Write a program that talks to a database on the local machine
- Start a virtual server instance on a service such as AWS and run stuff on it

For a beginner, NodeJS and MongoDB are particularly easy to do this with.

Later it might be a better idea to use an already-made API like Unai mentions, but trying this out yourself first will give you a better understanding of how this all works.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Facebook scores API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/scores) for that ([how to integrate in unity3d](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/unity/unity-tutorial#opengraph_step1)).